# feedbackSlider.owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a developer but trying to implement a carousel template from this page to my page. https://speckyboy.com/spread-the-word-beautiful-testimonial-ui-examples/

The problem is in the title. I read a bit into it and might a some order problem? I use wordpress and a theme builder fyi. Can someone please help?
Here is the code:

HTML

```
<section>
  <div class="customer-feedback">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div>
            <h2 class="section-title">What Clients Say</h2>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div class="owl-carousel feedback-slider">

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/8/7310/buddyicons/24846422@N06_r.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Lisa Redfern</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hnmqik4yn/image/upload/c_fill,fl_force_strip,h_128,q_100,w_128/v1493982718/ah57hnfnwxkmsciwivve.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Cassi</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="4">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Md Nahidul</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

          </div><!-- /End feedback-slider -->

          <!-- side thumbnail -->
          <div class="feedback-slider-thumb hidden-xs">
            <div class="thumb-prev">
              <span>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="thumb-next">
              <span>
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hnmqik4yn/image/upload/c_fill,fl_force_strip,h_128,q_100,w_128/v1493982718/ah57hnfnwxkmsciwivve.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /side thumbnail -->

        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->
    </div><!-- /End container -->
  </div><!-- /End customer-feedback -->
</section>

<!-- extra -->
<div class="copyright">
  <p>
    Me On:
    <a href="https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/users/_~0195eb53c731b0e159/" target="_blank" class="upwork">UpWork</a>
    <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/thenahidul" target="_blank" class="fiverr">Fiverr</a>
    <a href="https://triplebyte.com/iv/a35URkk/cp/header" class="triplebyte" target="_blank">Jobs</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var feedbackSlider = $(".feedback-slider");
  feedbackSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"
    ],
    responsive: {
      // breakpoint from 767 up
      767: {
        nav: true,
        dots: false
      }
    }
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translate.owl.carousel", function () {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3")
      .removeClass("animated fadeIn")
      .css("opacity", "0");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating")
      .removeClass("animated zoomIn")
      .css("opacity", "0");
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translated.owl.carousel", function () {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").addClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating")
      .addClass("animated zoomIn")
      .css("opacity", "1");
  });
  feedbackSlider.on("changed.owl.carousel", function (property) {
    var current = property.item.index;
    var prevThumb = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .prev()
      .find("img")
      .attr("src");
    var nextThumb = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .next()
      .find("img")
      .attr("src");
    var prevRating = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .prev()
      .find("span")
      .attr("data-rating");
    var nextRating = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .next()
      .find("span")
      .attr("data-rating");
    $(".thumb-prev").find("img").attr("src", prevThumb);
    $(".thumb-next").find("img").attr("src", nextThumb);
    $(".thumb-prev")
      .find("span")
      .next()
      .html(prevRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
    $(".thumb-next")
      .find("span")
      .next()
      .html(nextRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
  });
  $(".thumb-next").on("click", function () {
    feedbackSlider.trigger("next.owl.carousel", [300]);
    return false;
  });
  $(".thumb-prev").on("click", function () {
    feedbackSlider.trigger("prev.owl.carousel", [300]);
    return false;
  });
}); //end ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include `JQuery` and `OwlCarousel`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

please try this snippet :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var feedbackSlider = $(".feedback-slider");
  feedbackSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"
    ],
    responsive: {
      // breakpoint from 767 up
      767: {
        nav: true,
        dots: false
      }
    }
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translate.owl.carousel", function () {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3")
      .removeClass("animated fadeIn")
      .css("opacity", "0");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating")
      .removeClass("animated zoomIn")
      .css("opacity", "0");
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translated.owl.carousel", function () {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").addClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating")
      .addClass("animated zoomIn")
      .css("opacity", "1");
  });
  feedbackSlider.on("changed.owl.carousel", function (property) {
    var current = property.item.index;
    var prevThumb = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .prev()
      .find("img")
      .attr("src");
    var nextThumb = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .next()
      .find("img")
      .attr("src");
    var prevRating = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .prev()
      .find("span")
      .attr("data-rating");
    var nextRating = $(property.target)
      .find(".owl-item")
      .eq(current)
      .next()
      .find("span")
      .attr("data-rating");
    $(".thumb-prev").find("img").attr("src", prevThumb);
    $(".thumb-next").find("img").attr("src", nextThumb);
    $(".thumb-prev")
      .find("span")
      .next()
      .html(prevRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
    $(".thumb-next")
      .find("span")
      .next()
      .html(nextRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
  });
  $(".thumb-next").on("click", function () {
    feedbackSlider.trigger("next.owl.carousel", [300]);
    return false;
  });
  $(".thumb-prev").on("click", function () {
    feedbackSlider.trigger("prev.owl.carousel", [300]);
    return false;
  });
}); //end ready
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="customer-feedback">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div>
            <h2 class="section-title">What Clients Say</h2>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div class="owl-carousel feedback-slider">

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/8/7310/buddyicons/24846422@N06_r.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Lisa Redfern</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hnmqik4yn/image/upload/c_fill,fl_force_strip,h_128,q_100,w_128/v1493982718/ah57hnfnwxkmsciwivve.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Cassi</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="4">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Md Nahidul</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

          </div><!-- /End feedback-slider -->

          <!-- side thumbnail -->
          <div class="feedback-slider-thumb hidden-xs">
            <div class="thumb-prev">
              <span>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="thumb-next">
              <span>
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hnmqik4yn/image/upload/c_fill,fl_force_strip,h_128,q_100,w_128/v1493982718/ah57hnfnwxkmsciwivve.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /side thumbnail -->

        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->
    </div><!-- /End container -->
  </div><!-- /End customer-feedback -->
</section>

<!-- extra -->
<div class="copyright">
  <p>
    Me On:
    <a href="https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/users/_~0195eb53c731b0e159/" target="_blank" class="upwork">UpWork</a>
    <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/thenahidul" target="_blank" class="fiverr">Fiverr</a>
    <a href="https://triplebyte.com/iv/a35URkk/cp/header" class="triplebyte" target="_blank">Jobs</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: please vote up this answer, if helpful :)